# Mobile version - Site.Mobile.master

Tags: asp.net, mobile

I am looking into options with a mobile version of a website.
I need to have a different layout for mobile's so a responsive site is not the option.

I have been looking into the Site.Mobile.master in ASP.NET.
This seems to work for what I require, however a few questions:

1. How reliable is ASP.NET Site.Mobile.master for detecting a mobile? Will it pick up all types (iPhone, Blackberry, WindowsPhone, etc)?
2. When using the Site.Mobile.master it classes a tablet as a mobile too.
   Is there a way to have tablets to go to Site.master (instead of Site.Mobile.master) or even better is there a way to set up Site.Tablet.Master?
3. Is Site.Mobile.master the best way to build my mobile version.
   As mentioned I need to have a different layout with different HTML so responsive site is not an option. I like the idea of the URLs for the mobile / desktop been the same.

Thanks in advance.